# Help with tinymce to set different color value

Tags: css, tinymce

I have a web page integrated with tinymce, and I have my text area like this

```
<textarea name="descripcion" cols="45" rows="10" id="descripcion">
php echo $data->contenido
</textarea>
```

And i want to set 2 different Font color to this text area.

1. I want to set black color to whatever comes in the record set 
   `php echo $data->contenido`
2. I want to set red color to whatever the user modify manually in the text area.
   I am doing this because this is a document modification and I want to separate what we have in our records and what the user wants to change.

I would really appreciate if somebody can tell me how I can set different color (one that comes with the record set and the other one when the user writes.)

Thanks

Comment: because it's needed to change the normal behavior you need to use javascript. If you are looking for a pure css solution I don't think that exist.

Comment: WELL maybe there is a solution with jquery, the problems is how ????

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat tricky to achieve:

Before tinymce gets initialized you may use code like this to have all content from the database shown black

a)

```
<textarea name="descripcion" cols="45" rows="10" id="descripcion">
<p>
<?php echo $data->contenido; ?>
</p>
<p><br></p>
</textarea>
```

b)  You will need to set the editor contents css using the tinymce init [parameter content_css](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3acontent_css)

```
p { color: black; }

span.edited {
   color: red;
}
```

In order to colorize the user input you will have to use a mechanism like the one provided from the style plugin already integrated into tinymce. The difficulty here is that you will have to wrap everything you type into spans with the class edited. There are various ways to colorize your user input, but i think this one is probably the most promising one.

I suggest you insert such a span every time you click or use arrow keys to move the cursor. When they start typing the style will be applied. If they don't write but click somewhere else, the empty spans should get removed during editor cleanup.

Here is the event handler for onClick:

```
setup : function(ed) {
  ed.onClick.add(function(ed){
     ed.getDoc().execCommand('insertHTML', false, '<span class="edited"></span>');
  });
}
```

Comment: I follow everything you say but i am confuse about where to locate the onclick event, because I have this.
              
                <?php echo $data->contenido ?> </p>
                   <p><br></p>
              </textarea>
Where to put the OnClick event?. Should I put it on <p> tag ? like this ?
              <textarea name="descripcion" cols="45" rows="10" id="descripcion"><p>
                <?php echo $data->contenido ?> </p>
                   <p ed.onClick.add(function(ed){
   ed.getDoc().execCommand('insertHTML', false, '<span class="edited"></span>');
})
><br></p>

Comment: no, you need to use this as tinymce setting or place it inside your own plugin. Have a look at my updated post or/and here: http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/API3:event.tinymce.Editor.onClick

Comment: ok, now this function should be fire when i put textarea tag? or i should call function(ed) somewhere else.

Comment: this should insert a span-tag whenever you click inside the editor